# Interpolating Map Keys with Elixir

Tags: elixir

```
r = Date.range(~D[2019-07-01], ~D[2019-07-31])
q =
    %{
      ~D[2019-07-22] => 387,
      ~D[2019-07-23] => 256,
      ~D[2019-07-24] => 117,
      ~D[2019-07-25] => 1
    }
```

I've got a date range enumerable, and I'm trying to add `date => 0` for every date that isn't present in `q`.

This would be easy with a `for` loop, but that's not an option. I tried various `Enum.map` functions, I'm pretty sure that's not what I want. I think I want to be using `reduce`, but I'm not certain.

How do I approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Map.put_new/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html?#put_new/3):

```
Enum.reduce(r, q, &Map.put_new(&2, &1, 0))
```

---

Less performant version (it looks up the map on every iteration) with [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#for/1) comprehension:

```
for date <- r, do: {date, Map.get(q, date, 0)}, into: %{}
```